# Does use of Butterknife make UI Sluggish?

Tags: android, performance, dependency-injection

I was involved in discussion that should we use Butterknife or not?
The opponent told me that we should not use the Butterknife, since it uses reflection and inject code at runtime.

I told him that Butterknife works on compile time policy and it is lightweight library.

I also told him that Dagger is also works on same policy and due to great performance it is adopted by Google, I mean Dagger 2 is developed by Google
http://google.github.io/dagger/

But still we are not agreeing each other.
Please give your suggestion on this.

Comment: AFAIK both Dagger 2 and ButterKnife do use annotation processing on compile time. Dagger 1 used reflection I think.

Comment: Yeah I also think that, But my question is does butterknife make any performance impact while app is running

Comment: I don't think so. But I think it does call all the `findViewById` at once per activity, whereas if you did it manually on demand and had like 1K views that might be slightly faster. Dagger on the other hand is much more complex. [Here](https://medium.com/@lgvalle/how-butterknife-actually-works-85be0afbc5ab#.ai0h1citn) I found a good post on how ButterKnife works.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Also I read that post you mentioned, It was good explanation on working of Butterknife. But I did not find any point or any statement from which we can infer that, Butterknife does not make make any great performance impact.